# I am getting a invalid regular expression flag w error in the error console

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am getting an invalid regular expression flag w error stating this:

**Notice**: Undefined Variable: image_file_name in  **web/stud/...**

In view source it is pointing to a blank space underneath this line of code.

```
var image_file_name = <?php echo json_encode($image_file_name); ?>;
```

So how can this error be removed from the error console?

Below is the javascript function where the line of code is displayed:

```
 var _cancelimagecounter = cancelimagecounter;


    $(".imageCancel").click(function() {
    var image_file_name = <?php echo json_encode($image_file_name); ?>;

                  $('.upload_target').get(0).contentwindow
              $("iframe[name='upload_target']").attr("src", "javascript:'<html></html>'");

    jQuery.ajax("cancelimage.php?fileImage=" + image_file_name)
        .done(function(data) {

        $(".imagemsg" + _cancelimagecounter).html(data);
    });

    return stopImageUpload();

});
```

Below is the php code where it retrieves the variable `$image_file_name`.

```
<?php

...

$image_file_name = $_GET["fileImage"];

    echo "File Upload was Canceled";

        $imagecancelsql = "DELETE FROM Image 
        WHERE ImageFile = 'ImageFiles/". mysql_real_escape_string($image_file_name)."'";

    mysql_query($imagecancelsql);

    mysql_close();


?>
```

Comment: I'd have a guess that your php `$image_file_name` var is empty and thus prints an empty string in your JS code generating that error. Or better, it's printing `'<br/>` instead of the intended value apparently.

Comment: Use `var image_file_name = <?php echo json_encode($image_file_name); ?>;`. No quotes on the Javascript side, `json_encode` will produce a valid JSON string. If that string contains PHP errors instead of the filename, read what the errors say.

Comment: can you post the source that comes from the browser? not the one from your code nor the one from the console.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté To be honest I am guessing same as you, I don't think the file name is being retrieved at all :)

Comment: @Joseph When I go on View source it is displaying this line of code: var image_file_name = '<br/>

Comment: @user1384419 nothing after it? not even *a closing quote*?

Comment: Given the context, I definitely think `<br />` is the beginning of a PHP error message. Undefined (conditionally defined inside an `if(file_submission_happening)` block) variable?

Comment: @DCoder +1, I hadn't realized that yet. Most likely there's a php warning or error being echoed there. It just reminded me that in my very first Ajax app, I'd check if the response text started with `<br />` and handle it as a php error rofl (little off-topic, but that actually worked).

Comment: @DCoder When I try your json_encode method, it is giving me an invalid regular expression flag w error, what does this mean?

Comment: Edit your question to include the code you see when you view source, the entire `$(".imageCancel").on("click",` handler. It's probably printing the error right there.

Comment: Honestly, the error message seems obvious. The variable you're trying to print isn't defined - check the php code before the output and you should find a case where you're not assigning any value to `$image_file_name`.

Comment: cool, thanks DCoder, if you want to put your comment as an answer I will happily mark it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at all your quotes, you have another misplaced quote in your code along with misplaced quotes in `var image_file_name = '<?php echo $image_file_name; ?>';`

Answer (score 0):

remove quotes  `var image_file_name = '<?php echo $image_file_name; ?>';`

Comment: You tell what the problem is, but not why, and some would argue the why is more important.

Comment: I have tried using the var image_file_name = <?php echo json_encode($image_file_name); ?>; DCoder provided me but it is giving me an invalid regular expression flag w error. What does this mean?